# webapp networking: upload file and modify

Tags: javascript

I'm building a webapp that supports file modification. The use case is:

1. The user uploads an image file, which I'm guessing gets pushed to  server.
2. The server receives the image, and, using the `cv2` library, reads the image into a `numpy` array. It then does some computations on the `numpy` array, and there'll be a result returned, e.g., the average RGB tuple value, where the average is taken over each colour channel. (The exact computation is arbitrary - the point is that there's some Python logic being executed.)
3. Server returns the RGB tuple to the user.

I'm new to this, so that's my high level understanding of it, but I've got little idea as to exactly how to implement each step. (Frankly, I only understand "server" as "a separate machine somewhere out there that serves as a central command that client machines, like my laptop, can communicate with"). I've found some bits and pieces:

- [Uploading images through jQuery](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/)
- packages like AJAX or AXIOS that do routing, GET/POST requests, etc.
- Something called the Apache Web Server that comes up very often when I google "running Python scripts on a server".

I'm familiar with front-end scripting (HTML/CSS/JS), and Python scripting, but not on networking issues (passing a file, or results/JS objects back and forth the client/server, web hosting other than hosting simple static websites like Github pages), so I'm not even sure what terms to search.

Comment: You are in the right direction. you simply use jquery ajax (from your example) to post the file to the server (Python/PHP/JAVA). and you can simply do the calculation from that file and then send the response with the result as JSON data. That's it.

Comment: seems like you understand the issue fine to me...

Comment: Might be a prime example of how someone can fake his way into the software engineering world: I'm really just parroting terms I've seen and only have a high-level understanding of, without a practitioner's understanding (yet).

Comment: Unfortunately, this question is unlikely to really get the kind of answer you are looking for.  It is overly broad, and is really asking for people to tell you what tools you should be using rather than asking specifics about the tools you have chosen.  That kind of question isn't really answerable in this site format, as it is a matter of opinion as to which tools are best, and multiple answers could all be equally correct.

Comment: ask on /r/webdev